# Firebase displayname is null until log out then log in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm quite a novice at javascript. I am using Firebase, and have options to create an account (username, email, password), login, login through Google, and login through Facebook.

I want "testing" to display the displayName attribute from the Firebase User (which is obtained from the textfield "txtName").

This works when I log out and then log back in, or use Facebook or Google to log in. When I look at the console.log on firebaseUser, it's able to retrieve the displayName successfully. Of course, the problem is that when I want to do the innerHTML on it (if the account isn't Facebook or Google), displayName shows up as null.

I heard that it is a bug in Firebase. If so, is there any work around, without requiring the user to log out and then back in (unless it can be automatic)?

```
btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const pass = txtPassword.value;
  const name = txtName.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  // Sign In
  const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
  promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if(firebaseUser) {
      firebaseUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: name
      });
      console.log("display name: " + firebaseUser.displayName);
    } else { }
  });
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
  if(firebaseUser) {
    // User Logged in
    btnLogout.style.display = "block";
    testing.innerHTML = firebaseUser.displayName + "\n " + firebaseUser.email;
  } else {
    // User not logged in
    btnLogout.style.display = "none";
    testing.innerHTML = "Firebase User NOT Logged In!";
  }
});
```

Comment: updateProfile is asynchronous. Can you try
      `firebaseUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: name
      }).then(function() {
      console.log("display name: " + firebaseUser.displayName);
      });`

Comment: Still gives the same problem: when doing the console.log for firebaseUser it includes the correct values (including the correct displayName). However, after that, the console log that specifically retrieves for firebaseUser.displayName gives null.

If you want to inspect the source code and see how this works further, feel free to go to bradwyatt.me.

Comment: onAuthStateChanged will fire as soon as createUserWithEmailAndPassword finishes, so the user won't have their displayName set at that point. You could try updating the UI after updateProfile finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This sounds stupid, but I'm not sure how to make it so that the UI updates after updateProfile finishes. I created a Test Button that would change the innerHTML text to displayName, and that worked. But how could I do it automatically?

Comment: updateProfile returns a [Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises), so you can do `firebaseUser.updateProfile({ displayName: name }).then(function() { debugMsg.innerHTML = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName; });`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the help and explanations. Not sure what Stack Overflow etiquette is on this, if you leave an answer I'll mark it as the solution.